# Automatically resize iFrame height based on a change of it's contents height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Question about iframes and javascript here.

I've been trying for while to get an iframe to automatically resize it's height to the height of it's content.

The simple way to do it once is to use:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
...
iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.height;
```

But how can I get it to automatically change if the content height changes, for example adding a comment to a page.

Is there an event I can watch for (, I don't think there is)?.

I want to try and do this without jQuery, but will reluctantly go to it if it's necessary :) .

Comment: If you don't mind a slight lag, you can use a timer to check the height of the iframe content and resize the iframe when it changes.

Comment: Bear in mind that this will work **only** if both host page and iframe are in the same domain.

Comment: @MattBurland, thanks. I'll probably end up doing a timed check if there are no better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this after add new comment inside iframe but only if iframe is in the same domain

```
 $(window.parent.document).find('body iframe').height($('html').height());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't be on the same domain. Think youtube embed code.

Comment: Actually, this could be interesting.

The js file and the iframe will be pointing to the same domain, but the page "host" will be variable.